# Value coupon discount not applicable Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon-codes, discussion

Discount value is applied but is not calculated with the total amount.
[image: eerro]

Comment: Do you have any customization for total. or any module which override total model?

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. Without more information it's hard to help here. This does not happen in a vanilla Magento 1.9 installation. To debug, please try disabling checkout related extensions one by one, and also check if it works in the default theme.

Comment: Guys, there's no change in the default calculator module, I've tested it on the default theme, and it also does not work.

Comment: My problem has been solved with the module. My server uses PHP 7 version.
Module:

https://github.com/hartmut-ltd/magento-php7-totals-fix